# Exception.getCause() returning null when trying to find the source of an exception

Tags: java, objectinputstream

why does `System.out.println(e.getCause());` gives `null`?
And can store whole HashSet collection like this?

```
private void saving() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));

        out.writeObject(c);

    } catch (java.io.NotSerializableException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

---

Used `printStackTrace()` instead of `getCause()`

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Data$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashSet.writeObject(HashSet.java:284)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:962)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at Prozor.saving(Prozor.java:81)
    at Prozor.actionPerformed(Prozor.java:57)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6268)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6033)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2045)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4629)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4633)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4297)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4227)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2089)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2517)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Still do not see the problem, except that it snaped on first object of collection, and collection is implementing `Serializable`, all objects also implement `Serializable` and threads have transient where declared

Comment: There are cases where both getCause() and getMessage() will be null.  The only good solution is to understand what exception types are going to be thrown and handle them gracefully.

Answer (score 14):

When an exception is [chained](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html), the `getCause` method is used to get the original cause. In this case, the exception was not chained from any other layer, hence `getCause` returns `null`. You should use `e.printStackTrace()` instead, to get the reason for the exception. Most likely, this would be because one or more keys/values in your `HashSet` are of a type that is not implementing `java.io.Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printStackTrace()` instead of `getCause()`.

And yes, you can save a whole collection (as long as it holds objects that implement Serilizable).

Comment: When dealing with an exception mostly you can use printStackTrace() or getMessage() for simple exception message. In your whole Collection, all class inside should implements Serializable interface

Answer (score 0):

Below code gave me exact cause of the exception

```
try{
 // code
}
catch(Exception ex){
    Exception exe = new Exception();
    String causeString="";
    exe.initCause(ex);
    if(exe.getCause()!=null && exe.getCause().getCause()!=null)
     causeString=  exe.getCause().getCause().getLocalizedMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question - though it does help with further debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get cause.

```
private void saving() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));

        out.writeObject(c);

    } catch (java.io.NotSerializableException e) {
        System.out.println(e.fillInStackTrace());
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```