# JOptionPane gives a NullPointerException and is not displayed

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, try-catch, joptionpane

here is a code snippet

```
private void viewscriptJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){                                                  

    try{
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            scriptPane.setText(queryList.get(j).toString() + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"error:\n"+e.getMessage().toString() + "\n" + e.getCause().toString() ,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

The code inside catch block always gives a `NullPointerException` .This is just a reference. The problem occurs with every button click event whenever an exception is needed to be caught.
Any help.

Comment: I'm guessing the missing open `{` on the `try` line is just a copy-paste error?

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace() inside the catch block, and you'll get a stack trace indicating exactly where the NullPointerException happens.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @chrsblck- yes, im sorry . Its just a copy paste error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that [Exception#getCause()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29) returns `null` when the cause of the exception is itself, thus your `e.getCause().toString()` will throw a NullPointerException. The getCause method is generally used for finding the root exception when chaining them together.

[printStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) will print out the entire Stack Trace of the exception, allowing for an easier time debugging, however to fix this error, just change your JOptionPane statement to:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"error:\n"+e.getMessage().toString(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Also, you may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158817/exception-getcause-returning-null-when-trying-to-find-the-source-of-an-excepti).